# JBoss Deployment error: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: .war module listed in application.xml does not exist within .ear

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, jboss

I am using jboss-5.1.0.GA and jdk1.6. I have my stock.ear in C:\atgcertenv20120601\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\AllStocks\deploy\stock.ear.While running getting deployment error.Find the following error trace.

```
15:41:17,518 ERROR [ProfileDeployAction] Failed to add deployment: stock.ear
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Exception determining structure: Ab
stractVFSDeployment(stock.ear)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentExcept
ion(DeploymentException.java:49)
        at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers
.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:85)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(
MainDeployerImpl.java:1004)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeployment
Context(MainDeployerImpl.java:440)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainD
eployerImpl.java:390)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainD
eployerImpl.java:300)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter
.addDeployment(MainDeployerAdapter.java:86)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction
.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:61)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileActi
on.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileServ
ice.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(Abstra
ctControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(Abstra
ctController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileServ
ice.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(
ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:
461)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error determining structure: stock.ear
        at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.determineStructure(EARStructure.jav
a:293)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.de
termineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.
doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:196)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.
determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:221)
        at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers
.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:77)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: stk_bootstrap.war module listed in applic
ation.xml does not exist within .ear vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/AllStocks/deploy/ stock.ear/
        at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.determineStructure(EARStructure.jav
a:272)
        ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 4):

The war is really inside the ear? You can open the .ear with WinRAR or something similar and check.

Are you using Eclipse? If you turn off automatic build in Eclipse it doesn't create the war or ejb.jar before the packaging of the ear.
You could do it manually or enable it under Project -> Build Automatically.

Have you included the .war in the .ear project? Right click on the project, properties and check under 'Deployment Assembly'.

[image]

Comment: 'Build Automatically' has been enabled. But Still the `stk_bootstrap.war` is not getting created.

Comment: But Luke, I don't have an option 'Deployment Assembly' there.

Comment: Ah ok, strange...I don't know maybe you don't have Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers and only the classic (http://eclipse.org/downloads)?